# CreateProcess() lpCurrentDirectory has no effect

Tags: c++, winapi, createprocess

I want to start a process (exe file) and if I append the full path to my command line (lpCommandLine param) everything is fine but if I set lpCurrentDirectory to [STARTDIR] the system says:

```
ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

start the process:

```
CreateProcessA(NULL,                    // No module name (use command line)
            &command[0],                        // Command line
            NULL,                               // Process handle not inheritable
            NULL,                               // Thread handle not inheritable
            FALSE,                              // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
            CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,                 // No creation flags
            NULL,                               // Use parent's environment block
            [NULL] or [STARTDIR],               // Use parent's starting directory 
            startupInfo,                        // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
            processInfo)                        // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
```

-> In this folder are some other dlls and the exe I want to start

Why this doesn't work?

Thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that won't work. The new process won't be started with that directory as the "current" directory during the start. Instead, the current directory is set once the process has started.

If you want your process to start in a particular directory, then you need to use [`SetCurrentDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or one of the more or less portable variants thereof (`_chdir` for example).